# Retrieve generated LLVM from Numba

Tags: python, numba

After compiling a Python function with Numba such as:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y
```

how can I retrieve the generated LLVM code (as a string) of the compiled function?

It looks as though this was available in a previous version of Numba via the lfunc property of the compiled function, but this isn't working.

Similar functionality also appeared to exist in the form of [dumping the generated LLVM assembly](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/annotate.html) (during compilation). However, this doesn't seem to work anymore either - unless I'm doing something wrong. Having to run a terminal command would not be ideal anyway, as I would really like the code within Python, though I know I can do this with a subprocess.

This is to attempt to create a portable version of the Python code at runtime which will be translate; I welcome any suggestions relating to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't remember if this is the best way to do this, but if you don't mind compiling the function differently, you can do the following:

```
from numba.compiler import compile_isolated

# second argument specifies the argument types to the sum function
cfunc = compile_isolated(sum, (types.int64, types.int64))

# get llvm IR as string
llvm_code_str = str(cfunc.llvm_module)
```

The argument types need to be specified because the function isn't actually compiled until it knows the signature (either by specifying it explicitly or by actually calling the function).

The llvm IR can still be dumped from the terminal by setting the NUMBA_DUMP_LLVM=1 environment variable and running your python script (or using the numba command installed in the Anaconda bin path or in the bin dir in the Numba repo: numba --dump-llvm test.py).

Comment: Though you probably usually want NUMBA_DUMP_OPTIMIZED rather than NUMBA_DUMP_LLVM.

Answer (score 17):

For the record, starting from `numba` version `0.18.0` ([link to pull request](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/960)), the standard way to get the LLVM IR and assembly code is through the `inspect_llvm` and `inspect_asm` calls on the jitted function, for instance

```
@jit(nopython=True,nogil=True)
def mysum(a,b):
     return a+b

# First run the function with arguments for the code to get generated
a, b = np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)

# Get the llvm IR
mysum.inspect_llvm()
# Get the assembly code
mysum.inspect_asm()
```

Note that the returned values are in dictionary format. To display it in a readable (source code) format, just do

```
for v, k in mysum.inspect_llvm().items():
    print(v, k)
```

which will output a long piece of code

```
define i32 @__main__9mysum_...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Interestingly, as a side note, the generated assembly code shows that the for loop is completely unrolled by LLVM in the above function

```
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, -32(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, -24(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, -16(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, -8(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, (%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, 8(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, 16(%rbx,%rbp)
vmovsd  (%r10), %xmm0
vaddsd  (%rcx), %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  %xmm0, 24(%rbx,%rbp)
addq    $8, %rdx
addq    $64, %rbx
cmpq    %rdx, %rdi
jne LBB0_48
```

Comment: It might be an internal numba issue. It was officially added [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/a5027642923a17fbff218a9dd32a76564b401d91/CHANGE_LOG#L1556)