# How does numpy gain speed when the number of elements is less than 3-5 million?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, numba

Some numpy operations suddenly improve performance when the number of elements drops below a certain amount.

This is a function that uses numpy to find the maximum value of an array.

```py
def np_max(arr):
    return np.max(arr)
```

For comparison, here is a function that uses numba to find the maximum value as well.

```py
@numba.njit
def nb_max(arr):
    a_max = arr[0]
    for a in arr[1:]:
        a_max = max(a_max, a)
    return a_max
```

And this is the runtime measured with perfplot.

Code:

```py
def setup(n):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    return rng.random(n)


def benchmark_timeit():
    for f in [np_max, nb_max]:
        f(setup(100))

    n_run = 100
    for n in np.logspace(6, 7, num=30, dtype=int).tolist():
        arr = setup(n)
        np_max_time = timeit(lambda: np_max(arr), number=n_run) / n_run
        nb_max_time = timeit(lambda: nb_max(arr), number=n_run) / n_run
        print(f"n={n,}:"
              f" np_max={np_max_time * 1000:.2f}"
              f", nb_max={nb_max_time * 1000:.2f}"
              f", np/nb={np_max_time / nb_max_time:.2f}")


def benchmark_perfplot():
    for f in [np_max, nb_max]:
        f(setup(100))

    data = perfplot.bench(
        n_range=np.logspace(1, 8, num=8 + 7 * 9, dtype=int).tolist(),
        # n_range=np.logspace(6, 7, num=30, dtype=int).tolist(),
        setup=setup,
        kernels=[np_max, nb_max],
        equality_check=np.allclose,
        target_time_per_measurement=1.0,
    )
    data.save("./temp2.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    benchmark_perfplot()
    benchmark_timeit()
```

Result:

[image: numpy vs numba]

As you can see, there is a big jump between 10^6 and 10^7.
The results measured with timeit also confirm this.

```
n=(1000000,): np_max=0.11, nb_max=0.27, np/nb=0.42 <-- np/nb = numpy-runtime / numba-runtime
n=(1082636,): np_max=0.12, nb_max=0.30, np/nb=0.40
n=(1172102,): np_max=0.13, nb_max=0.32, np/nb=0.40
n=(1268961,): np_max=0.15, nb_max=0.46, np/nb=0.31
n=(1373823,): np_max=0.16, nb_max=0.38, np/nb=0.41
n=(1487352,): np_max=0.17, nb_max=0.41, np/nb=0.41
n=(1610262,): np_max=0.18, nb_max=0.45, np/nb=0.41
n=(1743328,): np_max=0.19, nb_max=0.48, np/nb=0.40
n=(1887391,): np_max=0.21, nb_max=0.52, np/nb=0.41
n=(2043359,): np_max=0.23, nb_max=0.56, np/nb=0.41
n=(2212216,): np_max=0.25, nb_max=0.61, np/nb=0.41
n=(2395026,): np_max=0.30, nb_max=0.69, np/nb=0.44
n=(2592943,): np_max=0.31, nb_max=0.72, np/nb=0.42
n=(2807216,): np_max=0.33, nb_max=0.77, np/nb=0.43
n=(3039195,): np_max=0.38, nb_max=0.88, np/nb=0.43 <-- 0.4
n=(3290344,): np_max=0.50, nb_max=0.97, np/nb=0.51      |
n=(3562247,): np_max=0.65, nb_max=1.07, np/nb=0.61      |
n=(3856620,): np_max=0.80, nb_max=1.19, np/nb=0.67      | 2x difference
n=(4175318,): np_max=1.00, nb_max=1.35, np/nb=0.74      |
n=(4520353,): np_max=1.11, nb_max=1.49, np/nb=0.75      |
n=(4893900,): np_max=1.25, nb_max=1.59, np/nb=0.78      |
n=(5298316,): np_max=1.44, nb_max=1.79, np/nb=0.81 <-- 0.8
n=(5736152,): np_max=1.57, nb_max=1.95, np/nb=0.80
n=(6210169,): np_max=1.71, nb_max=2.08, np/nb=0.82
n=(6723357,): np_max=1.85, nb_max=2.27, np/nb=0.81
n=(7278953,): np_max=2.02, nb_max=2.49, np/nb=0.81
n=(7880462,): np_max=2.17, nb_max=2.67, np/nb=0.81
n=(8531678,): np_max=2.44, nb_max=2.91, np/nb=0.84
n=(9236708,): np_max=2.61, nb_max=3.17, np/nb=0.82
n=(10000000,): np_max=2.81, nb_max=3.50, np/nb=0.80
```

My questions are:

1. What optimization made such a big difference?
2. Is it possible to reproduce it in numba?

Please note that what I want to accomplish is to gain knowledge about this optimization, not to beat numpy with out-of-the-box approaches like parallelization.

---

Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
- RAM 64 GB
- Windows 10
- Python 3.10.11
- numpy 1.26.2
- numba 0.58.1

---

Here is the LLVM IR and assembly code for n=10**6, where the performance difference with numpy is still large.

```py
def inspect():
    n_run = 100

    arr = setup(10 ** 6)
    nb_max(arr)
    print(timeit(lambda: nb_max(arr), number=n_run) / n_run)

    t = nb_max.inspect_asm()
    assert len(t) == 1
    Path("inspect_asm_10-6.txt").write_text(t[list(t)[0]])

    t = nb_max.inspect_llvm()
    assert len(t) == 1
    Path("inspect_llvm_10-6.txt").write_text(t[list(t)[0]])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # benchmark_perfplot()
    # benchmark_timeit()
    inspect()
```

`inspect_asm_10-6.txt`:

```
    .text
    .file   "<string>"
    .globl  _ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE,@function
_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE:
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %rsi
    pushq   %rdi
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    96(%rsp), %rax
    movq    88(%rsp), %r9
    movl    $1, %r8d
    cmpq    $2, %rax
    jl  .LBB0_10
    vmovsd  (%r9), %xmm0
    subq    %r8, %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    jle .LBB0_9
.LBB0_2:
    movq    104(%rsp), %r10
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    sarq    $63, %rdx
    andnq   %rax, %rdx, %r11
    movl    %r11d, %edx
    leaq    -1(%r11), %rax
    andl    $7, %edx
    cmpq    $7, %rax
    jae .LBB0_4
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .LBB0_6
.LBB0_4:
    movabsq $9223372036854775800, %rax
    leaq    (%r9,%r8,8), %rdi
    leaq    (%r10,%r10,2), %r14
    andq    %rax, %r11
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_5:
    vmovsd  (%rdi), %xmm1
    vmovsd  (%r10,%rdi), %xmm2
    vmovsd  (%rdi,%r10,2), %xmm3
    leaq    (%r14,%rdi), %rbx
    addq    $8, %rax
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vmovsd  (%r14,%rdi), %xmm2
    leaq    (%r10,%rbx), %rdi
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovsd  (%r10,%rbx), %xmm3
    leaq    (%r10,%rdi), %rbx
    leaq    (%r10,%rbx), %rsi
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vmovsd  (%r10,%rdi), %xmm2
    leaq    (%r10,%rsi), %rdi
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovsd  (%r10,%rbx), %xmm3
    addq    %r10, %rdi
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vmovsd  (%r10,%rsi), %xmm2
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    cmpq    %rax, %r11
    jne .LBB0_5
.LBB0_6:
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB0_9
    imulq   %r10, %rax
    addq    %rax, %r9
    leaq    (%r9,%r8,8), %rax
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_8:
    vmovsd  (%rax), %xmm1
    addq    %r10, %rax
    decq    %rdx
    vmaxsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    jne .LBB0_8
.LBB0_9:
    vmovsd  %xmm0, (%rcx)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    retq
.LBB0_10:
    movq    %rax, %r8
    vmovsd  (%r9), %xmm0
    subq    %r8, %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    jg  .LBB0_2
    jmp .LBB0_9
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, .Lfunc_end0-_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE

    .globl  _ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE,@function
_ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %rsi
    andq    $-32, %rsp
    subq    $224, %rsp
    vmovaps %xmm6, -32(%rbp)
    .cfi_offset %rsi, -24
    .cfi_offset %xmm6, -48
    leaq    88(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rcx
    movabsq $.const.nb_max, %rdx
    movl    $1, %r8d
    movl    $1, %r9d
    movq    %rax, 32(%rsp)
    movabsq $PyArg_UnpackTuple, %rax
    callq   *%rax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_1
    movabsq $_ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, %rax
    cmpq    $0, (%rax)
    je  .LBB1_4
    movq    88(%rsp), %rcx
    movabsq $NRT_adapt_ndarray_from_python, %rax
    leaq    96(%rsp), %rdx
    vxorps  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 96(%rsp)
    vmovups %ymm0, 120(%rsp)
    vzeroupper
    callq   *%rax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .LBB1_8
    cmpq    $8, 120(%rsp)
    jne .LBB1_8
    vmovaps 128(%rsp), %xmm0
    movq    144(%rsp), %rax
    movq    96(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    80(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    $0, 80(%rsp)
    movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
    movabsq $_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, %rax
    vmovups %xmm0, 48(%rsp)
    callq   *%rax
    vmovsd  80(%rsp), %xmm6
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rax
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    callq   *%rax
    movabsq $PyFloat_FromDouble, %rax
    vmovaps %xmm6, %xmm0
    callq   *%rax
.LBB1_2:
    vmovaps -32(%rbp), %xmm6
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rsp
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.LBB1_4:
    movabsq $PyExc_RuntimeError, %rcx
    movabsq $".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE", %rdx
    jmp .LBB1_5
.LBB1_8:
    movabsq $PyExc_TypeError, %rcx
    movabsq $".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type", %rdx
.LBB1_5:
    movabsq $PyErr_SetString, %rax
    callq   *%rax
.LBB1_1:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .LBB1_2
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   _ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, .Lfunc_end1-_ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE,@function
cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE:
    subq    $88, %rsp
    vmovaps 128(%rsp), %xmm0
    movq    144(%rsp), %rax
    leaq    80(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    $0, 80(%rsp)
    movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
    movabsq $_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, %rax
    vmovups %xmm0, 48(%rsp)
    callq   *%rax
    vmovsd  80(%rsp), %xmm0
    addq    $88, %rsp
    retq
.Lfunc_end2:
    .size   cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, .Lfunc_end2-cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE

    .weak   NRT_decref
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   NRT_decref,@function
NRT_decref:
    .cfi_startproc
    testq   %rcx, %rcx
    je  .LBB3_2
    #MEMBARRIER
    lock        decq    (%rcx)
    je  .LBB3_3
.LBB3_2:
    retq
.LBB3_3:
    movabsq $NRT_MemInfo_call_dtor, %rax
    #MEMBARRIER
    rex64 jmpq  *%rax
.Lfunc_end3:
    .size   NRT_decref, .Lfunc_end3-NRT_decref
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .const.nb_max,@object
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
.const.nb_max:
    .asciz  "nb_max"
    .size   .const.nb_max, 7

    .type   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE,@object
    .comm   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE,8,8
    .type   ".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE",@object
    .p2align    4
".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE":
    .asciz  "missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE"
    .size   ".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE", 128

    .type   ".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type",@object
    .p2align    4
".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type":
    .asciz  "can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type"
    .size   ".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type", 89

    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

`inspect_llvm_10-6.txt`:

```
; ModuleID = 'nb_max'
source_filename = "<string>"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"

@.const.nb_max = internal constant [7 x i8] c"nb_max\00"
@_ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE = common local_unnamed_addr global i8* null
@".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE" = internal constant [128 x i8] c"missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE\00"
@PyExc_TypeError = external global i8
@".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type" = internal constant [89 x i8] c"can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type\00"
@PyExc_RuntimeError = external global i8

; Function Attrs: nofree norecurse nosync nounwind
define i32 @_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE(double* noalias nocapture writeonly %retptr, { i8*, i32, i8*, i8*, i32 }** noalias nocapture readnone %excinfo, i8* nocapture readnone %arg.arr.0, i8* nocapture readnone %arg.arr.1, i64 %arg.arr.2, i64 %arg.arr.3, double* %arg.arr.4, i64 %arg.arr.5.0, i64 %arg.arr.6.0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
B0.else.endif:
  %.44 = load double, double* %arg.arr.4, align 8
  %.93 = icmp slt i64 %arg.arr.5.0, 2
  br i1 %.93, label %B0.else.endif.if, label %B0.endif, !prof !0

B24:                                              ; preds = %B24, %B24.lr.ph.new
  %lsr.iv9 = phi i64 [ %8, %B24 ], [ %16, %B24.lr.ph.new ]
  %a_max.2.04 = phi double [ %.44, %B24.lr.ph.new ], [ %.321.7, %B24 ]
  %.224.03 = phi i64 [ 0, %B24.lr.ph.new ], [ %.294.7, %B24 ]
  %.290 = inttoptr i64 %lsr.iv9 to double*
  %.291 = load double, double* %.290, align 8
  %.320 = fcmp ogt double %.291, %a_max.2.04
  %.321 = select i1 %.320, double %.291, double %a_max.2.04
  %0 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %lsr.iv9
  %.290.1 = inttoptr i64 %0 to double*
  %.291.1 = load double, double* %.290.1, align 8
  %.320.1 = fcmp ogt double %.291.1, %.321
  %.321.1 = select i1 %.320.1, double %.291.1, double %.321
  %sunkaddr = inttoptr i64 %lsr.iv9 to double*
  %sunkaddr11 = mul i64 %arg.arr.6.0, 2
  %1 = bitcast double* %sunkaddr to i8*
  %sunkaddr12 = getelementptr i8, i8* %1, i64 %sunkaddr11
  %2 = bitcast i8* %sunkaddr12 to double*
  %.291.2 = load double, double* %2, align 8
  %.320.2 = fcmp ogt double %.291.2, %.321.1
  %.321.2 = select i1 %.320.2, double %.291.2, double %.321.1
  %3 = add i64 %17, %lsr.iv9
  %.290.3 = inttoptr i64 %3 to double*
  %.291.3 = load double, double* %.290.3, align 8
  %.320.3 = fcmp ogt double %.291.3, %.321.2
  %.321.3 = select i1 %.320.3, double %.291.3, double %.321.2
  %4 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %3
  %.290.4 = inttoptr i64 %4 to double*
  %.291.4 = load double, double* %.290.4, align 8
  %.320.4 = fcmp ogt double %.291.4, %.321.3
  %.321.4 = select i1 %.320.4, double %.291.4, double %.321.3
  %5 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %4
  %.290.5 = inttoptr i64 %5 to double*
  %.291.5 = load double, double* %.290.5, align 8
  %.320.5 = fcmp ogt double %.291.5, %.321.4
  %.321.5 = select i1 %.320.5, double %.291.5, double %.321.4
  %6 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %5
  %.290.6 = inttoptr i64 %6 to double*
  %.291.6 = load double, double* %.290.6, align 8
  %.320.6 = fcmp ogt double %.291.6, %.321.5
  %.321.6 = select i1 %.320.6, double %.291.6, double %.321.5
  %7 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %6
  %.290.7 = inttoptr i64 %7 to double*
  %.291.7 = load double, double* %.290.7, align 8
  %.294.7 = add nuw i64 %.224.03, 8
  %.320.7 = fcmp ogt double %.291.7, %.321.6
  %.321.7 = select i1 %.320.7, double %.291.7, double %.321.6
  %niter.ncmp.7 = icmp eq i64 %unroll_iter, %.294.7
  %8 = add i64 %arg.arr.6.0, %7
  br i1 %niter.ncmp.7, label %B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa, label %B24

B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa:                           ; preds = %B24, %B24.lr.ph
  %.321.lcssa.ph = phi double [ undef, %B24.lr.ph ], [ %.321.7, %B24 ]
  %a_max.2.04.unr = phi double [ %.44, %B24.lr.ph ], [ %.321.7, %B24 ]
  %.224.03.unr = phi i64 [ 0, %B24.lr.ph ], [ %.294.7, %B24 ]
  %lcmp.mod.not = icmp eq i64 %xtraiter, 0
  br i1 %lcmp.mod.not, label %B38, label %B24.epil.preheader

B24.epil.preheader:                               ; preds = %B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa
  %9 = ptrtoint double* %arg.arr.4 to i64
  %10 = mul i64 %.224.03.unr, %arg.arr.6.0
  %11 = add i64 %9, %10
  %12 = shl i64 %.73.sroa.0.0, 3
  %13 = add i64 %11, %12
  br label %B24.epil

B24.epil:                                         ; preds = %B24.epil.preheader, %B24.epil
  %lsr.iv7 = phi i64 [ %xtraiter, %B24.epil.preheader ], [ %lsr.iv.next8, %B24.epil ]
  %lsr.iv = phi i64 [ %13, %B24.epil.preheader ], [ %lsr.iv.next, %B24.epil ]
  %a_max.2.04.epil = phi double [ %.321.epil, %B24.epil ], [ %a_max.2.04.unr, %B24.epil.preheader ]
  %.290.epil = inttoptr i64 %lsr.iv to double*
  %.291.epil = load double, double* %.290.epil, align 8
  %.320.epil = fcmp ogt double %.291.epil, %a_max.2.04.epil
  %.321.epil = select i1 %.320.epil, double %.291.epil, double %a_max.2.04.epil
  %lsr.iv.next = add i64 %lsr.iv, %arg.arr.6.0
  %lsr.iv.next8 = add nsw i64 %lsr.iv7, -1
  %epil.iter.cmp.not = icmp eq i64 %lsr.iv.next8, 0
  br i1 %epil.iter.cmp.not, label %B38, label %B24.epil, !llvm.loop !1

B38:                                              ; preds = %B24.epil, %B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa, %B0.endif
  %a_max.2.0.lcssa = phi double [ %.44, %B0.endif ], [ %.321.lcssa.ph, %B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa ], [ %.321.epil, %B24.epil ]
  store double %a_max.2.0.lcssa, double* %retptr, align 8
  ret i32 0

B0.endif:                                         ; preds = %B0.else.endif, %B0.else.endif.if
  %.73.sroa.0.0 = phi i64 [ %arg.arr.5.0, %B0.else.endif.if ], [ 1, %B0.else.endif ]
  %.161 = sub i64 %arg.arr.5.0, %.73.sroa.0.0
  %.168.inv = icmp sgt i64 %.161, 0
  %.170 = select i1 %.168.inv, i64 %.161, i64 0
  br i1 %.168.inv, label %B24.lr.ph, label %B38

B24.lr.ph:                                        ; preds = %B0.endif
  %.186 = getelementptr double, double* %arg.arr.4, i64 %.73.sroa.0.0
  %14 = add nsw i64 %.170, -1
  %xtraiter = and i64 %.170, 7
  %15 = icmp ult i64 %14, 7
  br i1 %15, label %B38.loopexit.unr-lcssa, label %B24.lr.ph.new

B24.lr.ph.new:                                    ; preds = %B24.lr.ph
  %16 = ptrtoint double* %.186 to i64
  %unroll_iter = and i64 %.170, 9223372036854775800
  %17 = mul i64 %arg.arr.6.0, 3
  br label %B24

B0.else.endif.if:                                 ; preds = %B0.else.endif
  br label %B0.endif
}

define i8* @_ZN7cpython8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE(i8* nocapture readnone %py_closure, i8* %py_args, i8* nocapture readnone %py_kws) local_unnamed_addr {
entry:
  %.5 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %.6 = call i32 (i8*, i8*, i64, i64, ...) @PyArg_UnpackTuple(i8* %py_args, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8], [7 x i8]* @.const.nb_max, i64 0, i64 0), i64 1, i64 1, i8** nonnull %.5)
  %.7 = icmp eq i32 %.6, 0
  %.21 = alloca { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }, align 8
  %.43 = alloca double, align 8
  br i1 %.7, label %common.ret, label %entry.endif, !prof !0

common.ret:                                       ; preds = %entry.endif.endif.endif.thread, %entry, %entry.endif.endif.endif.endif, %entry.endif.if
  %common.ret.op = phi i8* [ null, %entry.endif.if ], [ %.67, %entry.endif.endif.endif.endif ], [ null, %entry ], [ null, %entry.endif.endif.endif.thread ]
  ret i8* %common.ret.op

entry.endif:                                      ; preds = %entry
  %.11 = load i8*, i8** @_ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE, align 8
  %.16 = icmp eq i8* %.11, null
  br i1 %.16, label %entry.endif.if, label %entry.endif.endif, !prof !0

entry.endif.if:                                   ; preds = %entry.endif
  call void @PyErr_SetString(i8* nonnull @PyExc_RuntimeError, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @".const.missing Environment: _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE", i64 0, i64 0))
  br label %common.ret

entry.endif.endif:                                ; preds = %entry.endif
  %.20 = load i8*, i8** %.5, align 8
  %.24 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  %0 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(56) %0, i8 0, i64 56, i1 false)
  %.25 = call i32 @NRT_adapt_ndarray_from_python(i8* %.20, i8* nonnull %.24)
  %1 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  %sunkaddr = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %1, i64 24
  %2 = bitcast i8* %sunkaddr to i64*
  %.29 = load i64, i64* %2, align 8
  %.30 = icmp ne i64 %.29, 8
  %.31 = icmp ne i32 %.25, 0
  %.32 = or i1 %.31, %.30
  br i1 %.32, label %entry.endif.endif.endif.thread, label %entry.endif.endif.endif.endif, !prof !0

entry.endif.endif.endif.thread:                   ; preds = %entry.endif.endif
  call void @PyErr_SetString(i8* nonnull @PyExc_TypeError, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([89 x i8], [89 x i8]* @".const.can't unbox array from PyObject into native value.  The object maybe of a different type", i64 0, i64 0))
  br label %common.ret

entry.endif.endif.endif.endif:                    ; preds = %entry.endif.endif
  %3 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8**
  %.36.fca.0.load = load i8*, i8** %3, align 8
  %4 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  %sunkaddr3 = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %4, i64 32
  %5 = bitcast i8* %sunkaddr3 to double**
  %.36.fca.4.load = load double*, double** %5, align 8
  %6 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  %sunkaddr4 = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %6, i64 40
  %7 = bitcast i8* %sunkaddr4 to i64*
  %.36.fca.5.0.load = load i64, i64* %7, align 8
  %8 = bitcast { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] }* %.21 to i8*
  %sunkaddr5 = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %8, i64 48
  %9 = bitcast i8* %sunkaddr5 to i64*
  %.36.fca.6.0.load = load i64, i64* %9, align 8
  store double 0.000000e+00, double* %.43, align 8
  %.49 = call i32 @_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE(double* nonnull %.43, { i8*, i32, i8*, i8*, i32 }** nonnull undef, i8* undef, i8* undef, i64 undef, i64 undef, double* %.36.fca.4.load, i64 %.36.fca.5.0.load, i64 %.36.fca.6.0.load) #1
  %.59 = load double, double* %.43, align 8
  call void @NRT_decref(i8* %.36.fca.0.load)
  %.67 = call i8* @PyFloat_FromDouble(double %.59)
  br label %common.ret
}

declare i32 @PyArg_UnpackTuple(i8*, i8*, i64, i64, ...) local_unnamed_addr

declare void @PyErr_SetString(i8*, i8*) local_unnamed_addr

declare i32 @NRT_adapt_ndarray_from_python(i8* nocapture, i8* nocapture) local_unnamed_addr

declare i8* @PyFloat_FromDouble(double) local_unnamed_addr

; Function Attrs: nofree norecurse nosync nounwind
define double @cfunc._ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE({ i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] } %.1) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %.3 = alloca double, align 8
  store double 0.000000e+00, double* %.3, align 8
  %extracted.data = extractvalue { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] } %.1, 4
  %extracted.shape = extractvalue { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] } %.1, 5
  %.7 = extractvalue [1 x i64] %extracted.shape, 0
  %extracted.strides = extractvalue { i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64] } %.1, 6
  %.8 = extractvalue [1 x i64] %extracted.strides, 0
  %.9 = call i32 @_ZN8__main__6nb_maxB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dE5ArrayIdLi1E1C7mutable7alignedE(double* nonnull %.3, { i8*, i32, i8*, i8*, i32 }** nonnull undef, i8* undef, i8* undef, i64 undef, i64 undef, double* %extracted.data, i64 %.7, i64 %.8) #1
  %.19 = load double, double* %.3, align 8
  ret double %.19
}

; Function Attrs: noinline
define linkonce_odr void @NRT_decref(i8* %.1) local_unnamed_addr #1 {
.3:
  %.4 = icmp eq i8* %.1, null
  br i1 %.4, label %common.ret1, label %.3.endif, !prof !0

common.ret1:                                      ; preds = %.3, %.3.endif
  ret void

.3.endif:                                         ; preds = %.3
  fence release
  %.8 = bitcast i8* %.1 to i64*
  %.4.i = atomicrmw sub i64* %.8, i64 1 monotonic, align 8
  %.10 = icmp eq i64 %.4.i, 1
  br i1 %.10, label %.3.endif.if, label %common.ret1, !prof !0

.3.endif.if:                                      ; preds = %.3.endif
  fence acquire
  tail call void @NRT_MemInfo_call_dtor(i8* nonnull %.1)
  ret void
}

declare void @NRT_MemInfo_call_dtor(i8*) local_unnamed_addr

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nofree nounwind willreturn writeonly
declare void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* nocapture writeonly, i8, i64, i1 immarg) #2

attributes #0 = { nofree norecurse nosync nounwind }
attributes #1 = { noinline }
attributes #2 = { argmemonly nofree nounwind willreturn writeonly }

!0 = !{!"branch_weights", i32 1, i32 99}
!1 = distinct !{!1, !2}
!2 = !{!"llvm.loop.unroll.disable"}
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the [cache sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) of the processor you are running your tests on?

Comment: @JohanC I thought the same thing. But since numba does not show the same trend, numpy must be doing something more even if that is the case. However, I have no idea how to do it with an operation that accesses each element only once.

Comment: Looks like library overhead to me, i.e. an fixed operations that takes a fixed amount of time independently of the data. The absolute time is quite small (microsecond scale).

Comment: Please provide the generated ASM code, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213137/retrieve-generated-llvm-from-numba I'm curious if numba may generate a loop-carried dependency chain or otherwise vectorize inefficiently compared to numpy.

Comment: @mozway For sizes below 10^4, yes, I agree. But this question is focused on the sudden performance drop between 10^6 and 10^7.

Comment: @ken I agree with JohanC. Maybe numpy uses cache a bit better than numba and achieves better performance.. until it hits cache size. With today processor's cache sizes around `8-16MB` fits perfectly your `10^6 -10^7` interval given float64/int64 data

Comment: @Homer512 I have added the assembly code at the bottom. Please let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: @ken I thought your meant the initial difference, indeed the shoulder around 10^7 looks like something to do with caching.

Comment: Somehow I hadn't noticed it, but numba also shows a slight performance drop at the same area. It's just relatively small. So I assume that the performance drop is due to exceeding the cache size, which is why it happened to both, and the performance difference between them is how well numpy can use the cache, which is why it does not apply to above 10**7.

Comment: What you can see when you search the assembly for `max` instructions, is that you only find scalar `vmaxsd` and no vectorized `vmaxpd`. So the JIT compiler is not smart enough to vectorize. You also see that each `vmaxsd` takes the previous one as its input. So with [Zen3's 1 clock instruction latency for `vmaxsd`](https://uops.info/table.html?search=vmaxsd&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_ZEN3=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_doc=on&cb_base=on&cb_avx=on), you can only do one double per cycle. Once you run out of cache and become memory-bound, this is enough to keep up with numpy

Comment: Also note that if you are going to use `for-loop` with 2 numbers, then better use `ifelse` ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281691/why-is-max-function-so-much-slower-when-comparing-2-elements-vs-direct-compari

Answer (score 1):

I was able to squeeze additional performance by manually unrolling the loop (but `np.max` is still faster). It all depends on the processor and how it handles cache and prefetches the values from the memory:

```py
@numba.njit
def nb_max(arr):
    ma = mb = mc = md = -np.inf
    for a, b, c, d in zip(
        arr[::4],
        arr[1::4],
        arr[2::4],
        arr[3::4],
    ):
        ma = max(a, ma)
        mb = max(b, mb)
        mc = max(c, mc)
        md = max(d, md)

    m = max(ma, mb, mc, md)

    # compute the rest:
    if len(arr) % 4 != 0:
        a_max = arr[len(arr) - 3]
        for a in arr[len(arr) - 2 :]:
            a_max = max(a_max, a)
        return max(m, a_max)

    return m
```

On my machine (AMD 5700x) and for array of `float64`s creates this graph:

[image]